# Вываливается стектрейс, не попадая в @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
HttpResponse response; 
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
   response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
   if (response != null && response.getStatusLine() != null)//валится ошибка UnknownHostException 
}catch(UnknownHostException e){
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException(e.getMessage);
}
```

Добрый день, уважаемые коллеги разработчики, проблема у меня возникла такая: вываливается стектрейс с `ResourceNotFoundException` ошибкой, она почему - то не отлавливается в `ControllerAdvice`, в чем может быть проблема?

`ResourceNotFoundException` обработка в ControllerAdvice имеется

Используется: `@RestControllerAdvice`

ControllerAdvice:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
       @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        return buildResponseEntity(ex.getMessage());
    }

        private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ErrorResult apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class ErrorResult {
        private int code;
        private HttpStatus status;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        private LocalDateTime timestamp;
        private String message;
        private String debugMessage;
        private String messageInfo;

        private ErrorResult() {
            timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        }

        ErrorResult(HttpStatus status) {
            this();
            this.status = status;
            this.code = status.value();
        }

        ErrorResult(HttpStatus status, Throwable ex) {
            this();
            this.status = status;
            this.message = "Unexpected error";
            this.debugMessage = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

        ErrorResult(HttpStatus status, String message, Throwable ex) {
            this();
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
            this.debugMessage = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Если что-то не понятно в моем вопросе, пишите об этом в комментарии, поправлю

Comment: Приведите код вашей обработки в `ControllerAdvice`

Comment: @FirstSin добавил

Comment: Вот что написано в документации к этой аннотации `NOTE: @RestControllerAdvice is processed if an appropriate HandlerMapping-HandlerAdapter pair is configured such as the RequestMappingHandlerMapping-RequestMappingHandlerAdapter pair which are the default in the MVC Java config and the MVC namespace.` Может из-за этого и не срабатывает?

Comment: @Иван единственный адекватный ответ, благодарю

Comment: @Иван но вот опять же, сервис помечен @ Service и во всех других сервисах контроллер эдвайс проходит, может быть причина в том, что ошибка создается внутри catch?

Comment: Давайте, для начала кое-что сделаем: 1) перезапустите приложение и посмотрите, что нет никаких ошибок, далее 2) пометье метод как публичный, не защищенный. 3) если не отлавливается, замените на Exception (or Throwable) class, возможно выкидывается совсем другая ошибка

Comment: @Иван в кетч заходит в дебаге проверял

Comment: @Иван блииииин не выпадает в сокетах, там наверное свой хендлер нужен